# Why is this C# method overloading not working as expected?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following methods:

```
public void Say<TItem>(TItem item)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
}

public void Say<TItem>(IEnumerable<TItem> items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

When I run the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Say<string>("Foo");
    Say(new string[] { "Foo", "Bar"});

}
```

The first method is invoked twice:

```
A
A
```

Note changing the `IEnumerable<T>` to a `TItem[]` does work as expected but in the case of the `IEnumerable<T>` why is it not picking up the second method? How can I achieve the intended overloading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it thinks that `TItem` is `string[].` Look at this from the perspective of the compiler: All it knows is that it is looking for a generic type to plug into that method. It just so happens that string[] is a type. Because the meaning here is potentially ambiguous, you need to give the compiler some help to select which overload you are looking for here:

```
Say<string>(new string[]{"Foo", "Bar"});
```

should be enough to get it to select the method you actually wanted.

Comment: Great, but why is this extra help not required if the parameter type is `string[]` as opposed to `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @MaYaN In both cases your call could potentially match both signatures. When the method takes an `IEnumerable`, an implicit cast is needed to match, where for the other method requires no such cast. In the complier's mind, that makes the first overload a closer match. When you get more specific, the compiler is able to better infer what you were trying to do.